# Angular 2 SwitchCase with Fade In

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular

Hey everybody I'm having trouble trying to get my switch cases to fade in after one is called.

Here are my codes. If I were to type in the right switch case inside the input field I wanna be able to fade out the current one and fade in the new one

I would I go about that?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" (keyup)="changeData()" [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="write here">
<p>Now Displaying {{name}}</p>
<div [ngSwitch]="switcher">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'one'" [ngClass]="{'myfadeIn': fadeIn}">
        <p>switch case one</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'two'" [ngClass]="{'myfadeIn': fadeIn}">
        <p>switch case two</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'three'" [ngClass]="{'myfadeIn': fadeIn}">
        <p>switch case three</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myfadeOut{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}


.myfadeIn{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

**ANGULAR2**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "home",
    styleUrls: ['client/modules/home/home.component.css'],
    templateUrl: `client/modules/home/home.component.html`
})
export class HomeComponent {
    switcher = "one";
    name;

    fadeIn = true;

    constructor() {

    }

    changeData(){
        this.switcher = this.name;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structural Directives, like `ngSwitch`, modify DOM, not hide elements. You can take a look at Angular docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#why-remove-rather-than-hide-.

I think your goal should be achieved just by CSS (focusing on NgClass and adding those 'one', 'two', 'three' comparison to its logic) or just by Angular (there are some animation utils).